How long would a stock of nuclear warheads and their delivery systems remain viable?
My world is recovering from a period of chaos lasting around 50 years, during which time many things were not maintained, or only sporadically maintained. My story takes place in (what used to be) a large powerful nation-state with the same technology that exists today.
Now there is a looming civil war. I would like nuclear weapons and MAD to be off the table for all participants.
Is 50 years enough time for fission or fusion warheads to no longer be viable, and/or for their delivery systems to fall into disrepair, such that nobody can turn the tables on their opponents by finding one of these devices and threatening to use it?

Additionally, there are so many possible delivery systems (ballistic missiles, cruise missiles, aircraft all the way down to people lugging atomic demolition munitions) that you should look at a separate question for any particular system you are interested in.  Note that we have had many questions about "how long would X remain functional after an apocalypse?" so check for existing questions first.

Maybe five years minimum
At fifty years without a complete refurbishment they won't fire

The EBW detonators have a shelf life of five years. Unless someone can make detonators to replace them, the nuke is a dud.

This is just the detonators. The plastic explosive charges have a shelf life., the wiring, battery and even the circuit boards will eventually become unreliable.
A lot of different countries are already facing a similar problem with the missiles going to Ukraine as they need to be refurbished before they can be used reliably.

Excellent answer - was going to say something similar - that it is all the supporting components that will probably conk out before the Fissile material.

@TheDemonLord The best you could use an old nuke for is a cobbled together dirty bomb

Also, if it is a tritium-boosted design, the decay of tritium (~12.32 years half-life) will gradually turn the tritium into the nuclear poison helium-3.
